# How to develop Cart models and Cart Items model in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, model, cart

I am trying to create models for backend in django rest framework. Most of the developers I saw used two models namely Cart and Cart Items for creating cart which is as follows:

```
class Cart(models.Model):

    owner = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                 related_name="cart",
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True)
    number_of_items = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,
                                max_digits=5,
                                decimal_places=2)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"User: {self.owner}, items in cart {self.number_of_items}"


class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I am confused as to why one has to create two models. What is the actual use for it? And isnt the item should be many to many fields instead of the foreign key because we are supposed to add multiple products on the cart.

2. Also, why is there number_of_items and also quantity at same time? What is the difference??

My proposed model:

class Cart(models.Model):

```
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name="cart",
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True)
    item = models.ManytoManyField(Product,blank =True, null =True)

    number_of_items = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,
                                max_digits=5,
                                decimal_places=2)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Saroj Paudel - This is what I had used for my Cart Model in my e-commerce project. I had one model for the cart. That is the cartitem that had a reference to the product_id, user_id, quantity(number of items in the cart), and the date_added.

1 Product can belong to 1 or many cartitem and 1 cartitem can have 1 or many products. So, essentially it's an M2M but I am opting for 1 to Many as I don't see any harm other than the fact that my product_id might be repeating many items for different users but I am ok with that repetition.

```
class CartItem(TimeStampedModel):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, unique=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```